# Adding action item to action bar that directly opens a link

Tags: android, android-actionbar

What's the simplest way to add an action item to the action bar that is directly linked to a specific URL? Meaning, I tap an action bar icon and it loads a URL. The activity is already a webview and I want that action item to open the designated URL within the same activity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

on your menu item do this

```
loadUrl("www.google.com");
```

or

```
super.loadUrl("www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it, and I'm not sure if it is the best way:
I would declare at `menu.xml` my `MenuItem` as usual with `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`
and then:

```
@override
public boolean  onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch(item.getItemId() {
  case R.id.myActionItem:
  // get a reference to your webView and load new content
  break;
  default:
   break;
 }
 return true;
}
```

I hope I helpded.